# Can I use Python 2.7 and 3.7 at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7

I have Python 2.7 which I use, but I need to have 3.7 for a different program. Whenever I try to install it, it tries to go through 2.7 even though I have both. So is it possible? If so, how do I go about installing the program with 3.7?

Comment: Most OS's support a mechanism todo so, but if you want more direct assistance, you'll need to describe your environment

Comment: What OS are you using? You could use something like conda for this

Comment: Isn't there already plenty of information available on this subject?